# affine variety/space vs. toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, toric-geometry

I think I'm not quite clear on the meaning of a toric variety...

> Could someone explain the relation/difference between the affine variety/space and the toric variety?

I know that affine variety can be regarded as a subset of affine space, but not clear on their relation to the toric variety. Thanks!

Comment: Well I wouldn't worry about what a toric variety is until you have a plenty good understanding of what an affine variety is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is:

> Not every affine variety is a toric variety. Also, not every toric variety is an affine variety.

The most fundamental examples are projective spaces $\Bbb P^n$. Projective spaces are toric varieties but not affine varieties.

Recall that affine varieties are of the form $X=\Bbb V(\mathfrak a)$ for an ideal $\mathfrak a\subseteq\Bbb C[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$.

It would then make sense for affine *toric* varieties to be of the form $X=\Bbb V(\mathfrak a)$ for a certain kind of ideal $\mathfrak a\subseteq\Bbb C[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. This indeed turns out to be true.

> An ideal $\mathfrak a\subseteq\Bbb C[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is called *toric* if $\mathfrak a$ is [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) and generated by [binomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_(polynomial)).

One can then prove that affine toric varieties are precisely the affine varieties of the form $X=\Bbb V(\mathfrak a)$ where $\mathfrak a\subseteq\Bbb C[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is a *toric* ideal.

This gives a quick proof that the affine variety $\Bbb V(x^3-y^2-1)$ is *not* toric.

Obviously there's a lot more to say on the subject but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! This really gives a great starting point.